# Django Cannot install jdcal and et_xmlfile manually

Tags: python, django

I need to install manually for jdcal and et_xmlfile (copy file/folders) and I download from here.

https://pypi.python.org/simple/jdcal/

But it doesn't have init.py file and I got "**no module name**" error. How shall I do?

Comment: No module name....what? And it doesn't matter if it doesn't have a `__init__.py` what matters is the setup.py

Comment: I got no module name jdcal. How can I check whether setup.py is okay also?

Comment: Try searching how to properly install a package using setup.py. It doesn't seem like you even installed it. Why don't you just you pip?

Comment: I got it now. Thanks. I have to install with setup.py.